# Passing JSON containing a tags in GET variable to php

Tags: php, jquery, json, get

So I have a script that uses AJAX to pass a json string to a php file. I use `JSON.stringify()` a javascript array to a json string. The trouble is is the items in the array sometimes contain quotes (ie in the case of attribute for html tags). Here is an example json string that was generated:

```
[["CUGHDAA ID Equity","Cullen Global High Dividend USD","0.5","<a href="\&quot;&quot;#&quot;\&quot;">x</a>"],["XESX GY Equity","DB X Euro Stoxx 50","0.5","<a href="\&quot;&quot;#&quot;\&quot;">x</a>"],["ABEFROA LX Equity","Aberdeen Global Emerging Markets","0.25","<a href="\&quot;&quot;#&quot;\&quot;">x</a>"]]
```

`JSON.stringify()` escapes and html-encodes the quotes but when I pass the string to a php file via a GET variable my php file seems to not be able to receive it: the quotes seem to just mess everything up. What can I do to ensure the json string arrives at the php without messing up in GET form?

Edit: If I am to use POST how would I go about passing it via jQuery Ajax?

This is what I have so far:

```
var form = $(this),  
        formData = '&id=' + id + '&portData=' + JSON.stringify(tbl),  
        formUrl = form.attr('action'),  
        formMethod = form.attr('method'),   
        responseMsg = $('#update-response');  

        //add status data to form  
        form.data('formstatus','submitting'); 

        //Do the ajax
        $.ajax({  
             url: formUrl,  
             type: formMethod,  
             data: formData, etc...
```

Despite using `formData` variable name the data I am passing is not in a form but rather a set of javascript variables that are gathered on submit. How would I pass `id` and `JSON.stringify(tbl)` via POST instead of GET?

Comment: With that much data, you really should be using POST instead of GET.

Comment: Well, what you show is incorrectly escaped JSON. Where does that come from? What exactly are you receiving in PHP?

Comment: What I show is what is returned from `JSON.stringify`. This gets send unchanged as a get variable but is clearly messing things up as th quotes get unescaped when in URL form as the html-encoded quotes get treated as quotes with slashes before them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) to prepare a string for inserting into a URI.

---

Since your edits have revealed you are using jQuery ajax, don't build the query string manually at all. Pass an object to `data`.

```
data: { "id": id, "portData": JSON.stringify(tbl) },
```

Comment: The same way as any other query string data. `$json_text = $_GET['portData']`

Comment: Although you did answer my original question do you know how I might use POST instead of GET to pass my data as it seems more appropriate as the json could get quite long?

Comment: Yes but my `data` is passed as a GET string on the end of the target URL. Do I need to change it?

Comment: Saying `type: "post"` instead of `type: "get"` will change that.